# How can I uniquely identify a GameObject in Unity?

Tags: unity, serialization

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize my custom classes with Unity. I've got an `ISerialize` interface that mandates the class can `Load()` and `Save()`, so then I setup one master class to iterate across everyone and find the `ISerialize` components and trigger them to `Load()` and `Save()` correctly:

```
public class SerializationTest2 : MonoBehaviour, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    GameObject[] gameObjects = null;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        gameObjects = UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GetRootGameObjects();
    }
    // comment

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }

    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        Debug.Log("Unity is serializing... saving state!");
        foreach (GameObject gameObject in gameObjects)
        {
            Save(gameObject);
        }
    }
    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        Debug.Log("Unity finished serializing... loading state!");
        foreach(GameObject gameObject in gameObjects)
        {
            Load(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void Load(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Found {0}", gameObject.name);
        ISerialize[] serializers = gameObject.GetComponents<ISerialize>();
        foreach (ISerialize serializer in serializers)
        {
            serializer.Load();
        }
        int nChildren = gameObject.transform.childCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < nChildren; i++)
        {
            Load(gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void Save(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Found {0}", gameObject.name);
        ISerialize[] serializers = gameObject.GetComponents<ISerialize>();
        foreach(ISerialize serializer in serializers)
        {
            serializer.Save();
        }
        int nChildren = gameObject.transform.childCount;
        for(int i=0; i<nChildren; i++)
        {
            Save(gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

So this works GREAT and exactly as intended - I get a list of all the top-level root objects on `Start()`, then I get the serialize/deserialize callback. I iterate down the tree of GameObjects for each root and get everyone.

The idea here is that this class will eventually open an XML file and save to that file for serializing or will load from that file for deserializing.

I need to build that XML hierarchy, though. I could have multiple instances of a class scattered across a bunch of different GameObjects, so I need some way of identifying which GameObject I've currently got so I can serialize/deserialize to the correct components for that GameObject.

The problem is that, when I use the above code, I get:

```
UnityException: GetName is not allowed to be called during serialization, call it from Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'SerializationTest2' on game object 'Registrar'.
```

See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.

So, then, how do I uniquely identify the GameObject I'm currently on? If I can't call `gameObject.name`, what *should* I be calling?

:EDIT:

As an example, consider two enemies - one has a scale of 2x the other and a `hitDamage` of 2x the other, but they otherwise use the same `EnemyAttack` script. I need to deserialize the `hitDamage` values to the correct GameObject, but if I can't use the GameObject's name during the serialization process then I don't know how I'm supposed to distinguish the two.

Comment: Have you evaluated using [instance IDs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.GetInstanceID.html) for this purpose?

Comment: @DMGregory - I have, but my understanding was that [instance IDs are only constant across a particular scene and play session](https://answers.unity.com/questions/652911/a-couple-of-questions-about-instanceid.html). I'm ultimately looking to save and load the current state, so play can resume as-is across gaming sessions. If the instance IDs are only unique/valid to the current play session then they don't work for me for this purpose.

Comment: Names are not unique either. You can have multiple game objects with the same name in your scene.